# convert null values into empty string in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to convert all null with empty string I have used `array_walk_recursive` but I haven't got what I want please help me to figure it out what I have done wrong here.

```
protected function setData($key, $value)
{
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
    array_walk_recursive($this->data, function (&$item, $key) {
        $item = null === $item ? '' : $item;
    });
    return $this->data;
}
```

Comment: Try `$item = !is_null($item) ? $item : '';`

Comment: not working that too..

Comment: if($item === NULL){
$item = '';
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, that's just a lamp mistake in eloquent we always get result in eloquent object and here I'm passing eloquent object inside `array_walk_recursive` so before passing I need to convert into array from eloquent object using `->toArray()` method in laravel like this.

inside User Controller

```
$this->setData("friendList", $loadFriends->friends->toArray());
```

then `array_walk_recursive` will work.

```
protected function setData($key, $value)
{
    array_walk_recursive($value, function (&$item, $key) {
        $item = null === $item ? '' : $item;
    });
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
    return $this->data;
}
```

Comment: my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `array_walk_recursive()` method should be modified as follows.

```
array_walk_recursive($input, function($i) use (&$output) {
    $output[] = is_null($i)? '': $i;
});
var_dump($output);
```

`$output` contains the result you wanted. You can `return` it or do whatever you want to do with it.

**Note:** you can instead use `array_walk()` if `$input` not an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class InputCleanup
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $input = $request->input();

        array_walk_recursive($input, function(&$value) {

            if (is_string($value)) {
                $value = StringHelper::trimNull($value);
            }
        });

        $request->replace($input);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```