# How check the null items in object and return empty string

Tags: json, laravel-5.8

This is my object

```
$User = DB::table('user_app')
                ->where('id',$request->get('token'))
                ->select('account_type','address','card_bank','code_melli','shahr as city','family','id','mobile','name','phone','role','ostan as state','zip_code')
                ->first();
```

This is my json respons

```
"user_data": {
        "account_type": "real",
        "address": "سناباد",
        "city": null,
        "family": "حسینی",
        "id": 180,
        "mobile": "09371521106",
        "name": "الهام",
        "phone": "0513845555",
        "role": "usual",
        "state": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "خراسان رضوی"
        },
        "zip_code": "91387"
    }
```

Now i want to put null property empty string for example instead of city put "" value for APIs...
How could i do it

Comment: You can use a middleware  which converts the json to array, and use array_walk_recursive to convert all null to empty string, and then convert back to JSON . This shall take care of all your APIs at one go

Comment: is there any example that i can see ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert null values into empty string in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038644/convert-null-values-into-empty-string-in-laravel-5-4)